# Is this set neccesarily to be a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose $F$ be a field and $S$ be a non empty set such that
1) $a+b \in S $
2) $ \alpha a \in S$
for all $a,b \in S$ and $ \alpha \in F.$
Is always $S$ to be a Vector space?

Comment: Are you assuming any that the operations $+: S \times S \to S$ and $\cdot: F \times S \to S$ have any particular properties?

Comment: $S$ with addition must be an abelian group. $\phi: F\rightarrow\text{End}(S)$ determined by $\phi(\alpha)(a)=\alpha a$ must be a ring homomorphism.

Comment: @Travis: Ofcourse $S$ should be an abelian group under $+.$ Sorry I forget to mention that. Thanks drhab.

Comment: If $S$ is a subset of a vector space $V$, then the given conditions are sufficient to make $S$ a subspace of $V$. But without such $V$, the addition and multiplication are not related enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Take $F=\mathbb F_2$, $S=\mathbb Z$ and set $0\cdot a=0$ and $1\cdot a=a$ for all $a\in S$. Then you would have $0\cdot 1=(1+1)\cdot 1=1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1=2$, because in any vector space $(\alpha+\beta)a=\alpha a+\beta a$.

Answer (score 1):

No, for we could take the multiplication map $\cdot: F \times S$ to be zero map---the resulting structure fails to be a vector space only because it does not have a multiplicative identity, i.e. an element $1 \in F$ such that $1 \cdot s = s$ for all $s \in S$.

Ferra's nice example shows that preventing this degenerate solution by demanding existence of a multiplicative identity still isn't enough to guarantee that the $S$ is a vector space over $F$.